# Problem related to differentiate a integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I got no clue to solve this problem because I don't know any rule to differentiate an integral. Can someone give me a hint and list all the rules you know related to differentiate an integral? I really appreciate.

> > Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n}e^{-x}dx = n!$ by differentiating the equation $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx}dx = 1/t$.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a general theorem:

**Definition** The improper integral $I(y)=\int_a^\infty f(x,y)dx$ converges uniformly for $y\in\mathcal Y$, if for each $y\in\mathcal Y$, $I(y)$ converges, and $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists A_0\ge a,\forall A>A_0,\forall y\in\mathcal Y,\lvert\int_A^\infty f(x,y)dx\rvert<\epsilon$. In other words, $\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_a^Af(x,y)dx$ converges uniformly.

**Theorem** Suppose $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $[a,\infty)\times[c,d]$, and the partial derivative $f_y(x,y)$ is also continuous. If $I(y)=\int_a^\infty f(x,y)dx$ converges for each $y\in[c,d]$, and $\int_a^\infty f_y(x,y)dx$ converges uniformly for $y\in[c,d]$, then $I'(y)=\int_a^\infty f_y(x,y)dx$.

The proof is based on the following observation, which is too lengthy to be included, and the [Leibniz's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for proper Riemann integrals.

> If $f_\alpha'$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ as $\alpha\to\omega$ (a general limit process, characterized by, say a sequence, a parameter, or generally a [net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29)), and $f_\alpha(x_0)$ converges for some $x_0\in[a,b]$ as $\alpha\to\omega$, then $f_\alpha$ converges uniformly to some function $f$, and $f_\alpha'\to f$ as $\alpha\to\omega$.

For a reference, see W.Rudin's *Principles of mathematical analysis*, **Theorem 7.17** (but it's a sequential version. One can easily modify this proof), or the related chapter of V.A.Zorich's *Mathematical Analysis*, Vol 2.

In your problem, the integral (and its derivative with respect to $t$ indefinite times) converges uniformly on $[1/2,2]$, thus it's infinitely differentiable and the derivative could be determined by the preceding theorem, then let $t=1$.